# What permissions are needed for PLSQL execute immediate drop index

Tags: plsql

I have a standard DB procedure to drop indexes on a table (code below) created in user1 schema. When run as user2 the "execute immediate 'drop index" fails with ORA-01418: specified index does not exist.

I don't understand how the index can be returned by the cursor, but not exist when the drop command is run.

Can someone help explain the privs user2 needs on the user1 table/indexes and what AUTHID should be used?

```
create or replace procedure dropIndexes(pTableName IN VARCHAR2) AUTHID 
CURRENT_USER IS

CURSOR c1(pTableName VARCHAR2) IS
select index_name
from all_indexes
where table_name = pTableName;

BEGIN
   FOR c1Rec IN c1(pTableName) LOOP
      execute immediate 'drop index user1.'||c1Rec.index_name;
   END LOOP;
END dropIndexes;
```

Comment: I bet the owner is different than `user1`. `SELECT owner, index_name ...`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the obvious. the create index statement was run as user2 in the form 'create index <index> on user1.<table>...... I did not realise that user2 would own the index, I always thought that the index was owned by the table owner. Thanks for your help, this solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why not construct the SQL using the owner field of all_indexes. Better yet, push user1 into the query so we only get the index names that belong to user1.